# Why is を in this sentence: これからのお話を?

Tags: translation, meaning, particles, sentence

I’ve stumbled upon the sentence これからのお話を, which was translated “a story from now on” but why is を in the end and what is it’s meaning here?
As far as I know を is used to indicate direct objects but I don’t see any in this sentence.

Comment: Probably need the proceeding and/or preceding sentences to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これからの話を（する）The last part just being excluded.

Comment: I see, thank you